# Plotting the solution to a cubic equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm trying to plot the solution to a cubic equation in Mathematica. I can solve the equation numerically in numpy, I can get a a solution in Mathematica, but I can't get the plot I want in Mathematica.

```
R = 10;
w = 1;
Solve[
  L^3 - k L^2 w I + L l^2/(k^2 + l^2)(1 - 1/R) - l^2/(k^2 + l^2) w k I == 0, L]
ContourPlot[Re[max[L]], {k, -5, 5}, {l, -5, 5}]
```

How can I plot the solution successfully?

Comment: The function max needs to be Max[ ], for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like this?

```
R = 10; w = 1;
sol = Solve[L^3-k L^2 w*I + L*l^2/(k^2 + l^2)*(1 - 1/R)-l^2/(k^2 + l^2)*w*k*I == 0, L];   

SS1[k_, l_] := sol[[1, 1]][[2]];
SS2[k_, l_] := sol[[2, 1]][[2]];
SS3[k_, l_] := sol[[3, 1]][[2]];

s1 = ContourPlot[Re[Max[SS1[k, l]]], {k, -2, 2}, {l, -5, 5}, ColorFunction -> Hue];
s2 = ContourPlot[Re[Max[SS2[k, l]]], {k, -1, 2}, {l, -5, 5}, ColorFunction -> Hue];
s3 = ContourPlot[Re[Max[SS3[k, l]]], {k, -2, 1}, {l, -5, 5}, ColorFunction -> Hue];

Grid[{{s1, s2, s3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that looks great. Charlie.